# OCSP Responder (openca-ocspd) won't make

Tags: make, install-from-source

OCSP Responder is giving me a lot of grief.
I've tried installing it from OpenCA, but it encounters an error at `make`.
`configure` goes fine, and when I do `make`, it ends like this:

```
Making all in docs  
make[1]: Entering directory `/etc/ocsp/ded/openca-ocspd-3.1.1/docs'
/usr/bin/pod2man --section=3 \
                --c "OpenCA Contributed Manual" \  
                --r "openca-ocspd 3.1.1" ocspd.3.pod > ocspd.3
ocspd.3.pod around line 111: =over without closing =back
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 71.  
make[1]: *** [ocspd.3] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory `/etc/ocsp/ded/openca-ocspd-3.1.1/docs'  
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have compiled and installed `libpki` already (on which OCSP Responder is dependant), try to compile the Github repository's version:

1. Install `git`: `sudo apt-get install git`
2. Compile OCSP Responder in a "openca-ocspd" folder in your Desktop: `mkdir ~/Desktop/openca-ocspd && cd ~/Desktop/openca-ocspd && git clone https://github.com/openca/openca-ocspd.git && cd openca-ocspd && ./configure && make`

Comment: It works great, after I upgraded my libpki. Or at least the make and make install does. The only problem is that:
`-bash: openca-ocspd: command not found`

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus I didn't see the edit, you need to add a symbolic link to `openca-ocspd` (you probably can find one in `~/Desktop/openca-ocspd`)  in `/usr/bin`. If there's such symbolic link, just run `cp -p ~/Desktop/openca-ocspd/openca-ocspd /usr/bin/openca-ocspd`. Otherwise directly make a symbolic link (with the appropriate permissions) in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: I've found an excecutable: `src/ocspd/ocspd` has `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions. Not the same name as in the README though(openca-ocspd). Could probably just link it to bin that way. However, do you have any idea of where I can find the init scripts?(it's a daemon)

Comment: don't worry, I've managed to find the init script. The only thing I'm still missing is the config file

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus I can't check for it now, but I'll see if I can help you once home,  as of now I have no idea honestly